# Thin Controllers in Laravel 4

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to work out the 'best' way of structuring my controllers/models in a new Laravel 4 app.

Obviously I want to keep the controllers thin and lightweight. So I want to work with Repos/Services to separate things, however I don't really know how to implement this in Laravel 4. Laravel 3 gave us [some idea of how this should work](http://laravel.com/docs/models#best-practices), but no samples.

Has any one figured out the neatest way to do this, or have any sample code I could take a peek at?

Comment: that example is enough to start in my opinion.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, I just feel where to store the repos/services is not very clear, neither is the best way of accessing them.

Comment: here's the issue. to understand it, you need to come out of the model == database concept. The example was to show the design. You need to change it to suit your needs. e.g. you can have validator(for validation), database(only queries), processor(to process the request coming from controller, calculations), common(encapsulation of common methods shared by many classes) etc.... Different projects will require different approach. The example is suppose to give an idea, not to straightjacket. You need to extend it putting an eye in your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree on the fact that it isn't very clear where to store these classes in Laravel 4.

A simple solution would be creating repositories/services folders in your main app/ folder and updating your main composer.json file to have them autoloaded:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/repositories",
            "app/services"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Note: everytime you create a new class you have to run `composer dump-autoload`.

In case of repositories, you can have Laravel inject them into your controllers automatically. I find [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSt9rBa_oUM&list=PLOeImSGaWW197aY3PILEeZjiy9G5G4coU) a good screencast on this subject.

Comment: One of my questions with this is, why not create static functions inside the repository? Why did the example use a normal function that needs a repository instance to be created?

Comment: Static functions tend to cause issues with testability, which is a big focus in L4.

Answer (score 3):

I found this collection of tutorials to be a great introduction on the proper place to store your custom service providers and other files that you want to inject into your project:

- http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading
- http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-where-to-put-bindings
- http://fideloper.com/error-handling-with-content-negotiation

These tutorials come from this collection:

http://fideloper.com/tag/laravel-4

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that I do when I get a fresh install of Laravel is:

- Remove the "models" folder
- Create a src folder
- Under the src, create a Application folder (or the name of the app)
- On Application folder, create Entities, Repositories, Services and Tests

So, in this case your namespace will be Application\Entities, Application\Repositories and Application\Services

In composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Application": "app/src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/database/migrations",
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

To each one of those you'll need to create the classes and a service provider to bind a repository to an entity.

Here is a tutorial explaining how to create the repositories:

http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/

Anyway, I'm still looking for the best architecture. If anyone has a better idea, I'll be glad to hear it!